# Is there any idea to read one full column values from once data table and store it in array list?

Tags: c#, excel

I have tried with following code, but it is not giving correct value,

```
ArrayList = outTable.Select("[FILTER_FLAG]").ToList();
//outTable is my data table having values in the column name "FILTER_FLAG"
```

Comment: `ArrayList` is a type (in `System.Collections`), is there a variable involved? Does your code compile? What "value" is it giving? How do you know it's not correct?

Comment: For the type ArrayList , I have created one variable and tried to store one column values into it, 
I m using it in my RPA tool called UiPath, it is getting compiled, not  giving error, but not giving expected result also

Answer (score 0):

```
        DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();

        dataTable.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("ID", typeof(int)));
        dataTable.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Name", typeof(string)));

        dataTable.Rows.Add(1, "Mike");
        dataTable.Rows.Add(2, "Cris");
        dataTable.Rows.Add(3, "Ann");

        var _selector = dataTable.Rows.Cast<DataRow>().Select(x => x.Field<int>("ID")).ToList();

        ArrayList list = new ArrayList(_selector);
```